# Save state of progress bar in CSS

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am using [this example](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/responsive-step-progress-indicator-with-pure-css/) to create some kind of a checklist. I want to know if it is possible to save the state of the progress bar each time I close the application, and find the same state when I reopen it.

PS: I am using this example in an ionic application.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: PHP $_SESSION would be the bext way to save this data, or cookie's if you would prefer to use them

Comment: you could take a look at local storage https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/ & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage it is suppose to be there even that you turned off the computer  .. sqlite could also be an option

Answer (score 0):

You can use you database/session/cookie to store you last range, then put it in a variable `$rangeFromDBorSession` then use it in for loop.
For Example(PHP):

```
<ul class="progress-indicator">
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) {
   if($x<=$rangeFromDBorSession){
    echo '<li class="completed"> <span class="bubble"></span> Step $x </li>';
   }else{
    echo '<li> <span class="bubble"></span> Step $x </li>';
   }
}
?> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  localStorage

```js
.factory('sessionService',['$http',function($http){
return {
   set:function(key,value){
      return localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(value));
   },
   get:function(key){
     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
   },
   destroy:function(key){
     return localStorage.removeItem(key);
   },
 };
}])
```

in your CTRL

```js
.controller('exampleCtrl', function($scope, $localstorage) {
  $localstorage.set('key',value);
  
  var val =   $localstorage.get('key');
    
})
```